# LINQ - Dynamic OrderBy in VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

I am trying to do something similar to this sample code from Phil Haack to VB, and LINQ Orderby is giving me problems - and I can't figure out how to do this. Entire method posted for completenes.

This is the C# version:

```
    public ActionResult DynamicGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var context = new HaackOverflowDataContext();
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = context.Questions.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var questions = context.Questions.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from question in questions
                select new
                {
                    i = question.Id,
                    cell = new string[] { question.Id.ToString(), question.Votes.ToString(), question.Title }
                }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

My problem is with this line...:

```
var questions = context.Questions.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

In VB.Net OrderBy does not accept a string as value - and it seems to do that in C# (or I am missing something).

(Please not the use of VAR is not the issue here, I have that covered. :) )

**Edit:**
This is the error I get (I simply cannot compile):

Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'OrderBy' can be called with these arguments...

Screenshot of complete error message: [image]

**Edit2:**

More information, as requested.
sidx contains the name of a column to sort by
sord contains asc or desc

The VB-code:

```
Function MemberData(ByVal sidx As String, ByVal sord As String, ByVal page As Integer, ByVal rows As Integer) As JsonResult

    Dim allRecords As IQueryable(Of Models.Member) = Me.MemberRepository.FindAllMembers
    Dim currentPageRecords As IQueryable(Of Models.Member)
    Dim pageIndex As Integer = page - 1
    Dim pageSize As Integer = rows
    Dim totalRecords As Integer = allRecords.Count
    Dim totalPages As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / pageSize))

    Dim orderBy As String = sidx + " " + sord

    currentPageRecords = allRecords.OrderBy(Function(m) orderBy).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)

    Dim jsonData = New With { _
          .total = totalPages, _
          .page = page, _
          .records = totalRecords, _
          .rows = New ArrayList _
        }

    For Each member As Models.Member In currentPageRecords
        jsonData.rows.Add(New With {.id = member.MemberId, .cell = GenerateCellData(member)})
    Next

    Return Json(jsonData)

End Function
```

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: Just added a little more info in the original question. :)

Comment: What do the strings sidx and sord contain?

Comment: Could you also post your VB code that contains the error?

Comment: Dennis Palmer>> Added the vb-code and a little more info. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible he's using [Dynamic Linq?](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) With dynamic linq you can pass string to the OrderBy methods as well as many other of the IEnumerable extension methods.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I don't want to include more externals in the project, so I will look for another way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same as Kjensen, but i had a lot of problems (including the fact that the original C# sample has some bugs: revisitig the pages some results are ommited). So, i decided to modify the sample of Phil Haack (http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) using stored procedures (i never trust in a ORM-thing generating SQL Code, the stored procedure isn't the best but neither the code from Linq) and vb. net (i haven't clean the code and some comments are in spanish)

SQL Code

```
   Create procedure getDataPage1 
    (@tableName as varchar(100), 
    @columns as varchar(200),
    @columnOrder as varchar(100), 
    @columnOrderDirection as varchar(20),
    @currentPage as int,
    @pageSize as int, 
    @filter as varchar(2000) = '')
    AS
    BEGIN

    -- No se debe referenciar a otras columnas Identity (para esos casos se debe hacer un conversion previa antes de hacer el INSERT INTO)
    -- Version válida para Sql server 2000, usar funcion ROW_NUMBER para SQL server 2005 o posterior
    -- Ejemplos de uso: 
    -- exec getDataPage1 'DataTarjetasProcesada', 'linea = cast(linea as varchar(100)), Tarjeta, Bloqueo, Saldo', 'Tarjeta', 'desc', 6, 800
    -- exec getDataPage1 'Question', 'Id, Votes, Title', 'Title', 'desc', 2, 10



        set nocount on

        declare @query as nvarchar(1000)

        -- Paso 1: se numera el listado
        set @query = 'Select Identifier = Identity(int, 1, 1), ' + @columns  +
                ' into #temp ' +
                ' from ' + @tableName +
                case when @filter = '' then '' else ' where ' + @filter end + 
                ' Order By ' + @columnOrder + ' ' + @columnOrderDirection
        -- Paso 2: se toma la página de consulta
        +
        ' select ' + @columns  + ' from #temp '+
        ' where Identifier between '  + cast( @pageSize * (@currentPage -1) + 1 as varchar(15)) + 
        ' and '+ cast (@pageSize*( @currentPage ) as varchar (15)) 

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @query

        set nocount off
    END
```

Vb .net Code

```
   Function DynamicGridData(ByVal sidx As String, ByVal sord As String, ByVal page As Integer, ByVal rows As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim context As New MvcTestApplication.modelDataContext
        Dim pageIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1
        Dim pageSize As Integer = rows
        Dim totalRecords As Integer = context.Questions.Count()
        Dim totalPages As Integer = Math.Ceiling(CDec(totalRecords) / CDec(pageSize))

        ' Establecemos la función de ordenación dependiendo del valor del 
        ' parámetro "sidx", que es el campo de orden actual
        ' Establecemos si se trata de orden ascendente o descendente, en    
        ' función del parámetro "sord", que puede valer "asc" o "desc"

        Dim results As IMultipleResults = context.getDataPage1("Question", "Id, Votes, Title", sidx, sord, page, pageSize)

        Dim questions = results.GetResult(Of Question)()

        Dim jsonData = New With { _
          .total = totalPages, _
          .page = page, _
          .records = totalRecords, _
          .rows = (From question In questions _
                    Select New With _
                    { _
                        .i = question.Id, _
                        .cell = New String() {question.Id.ToString(), question.Votes.ToString(), question.Title} _
                    } _
                     ).ToArray() _
        }

        Return Json(jsonData)

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy takes a lambda expression; in this case, C# inferred one from the string being passed. VB, apparently cannot make that inferrence.

Try using `OrderBy(Function(str) sidx + " " + sord)`

Comment: Except that in VB it's preferrable to use & for string concatenation, though + works.

Comment: Sorry. C# developer here. :) Just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Randolpho. It did not work though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function MemberData(
        ByVal sidx As String, 
        ByVal sord As String, 
        ByVal page As Integer, 
        ByVal rows As Integer) As JsonResult

    Dim allRecords As IQueryable(Of Models.Member) = 
            Me.MemberRepository.FindAllMembers

    Dim currentPageRecords As IQueryable(Of Models.Member)
    Dim pageIndex As Integer = page - 1
    Dim pageSize As Integer = rows
    Dim totalRecords As Integer = allRecords.Count
    Dim totalPages As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(totalRecords / pageSize))

    Dim orderBy As String = sidx + " " + sord

    currentPageRecords = allRecords.OrderBy(Function(m) orderBy).Skip(
            pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)

    Dim jsonData = New With { _
          .total = totalPages, _
          .page = page, _
          .records = totalRecords, _
          .rows = New ArrayList _
        }

    For Each member As Models.Member In currentPageRecords
        jsonData.rows.Add(
           New With {.id = member.MemberId, .cell = GenerateCellData(member)})
    Next

    Return Json(jsonData)

End Function
```